# Canned corned beef dinner, for hiking

Tags: camping, corned-beef

Am wondering how to make palatable dinner with canned (European) corned beef (aka [bully beef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bully_beef), not the same as American [corned beef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corned_beef)).

This is for camping/hiking, so preferably not involving too many exotic ingredients and simultaneous operations. Assume a stove, a frying pan, a couple of pots.

Have seen suggestions for mixing it with left-over fried potatoes, but that assumes you have left-over fried potatoes.

Am looking for general suggestions, not detailed recipes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a dinner based on corned beef all from tins, but of course that's fairly heavy for hiking. Fresh veg cabln be lighter and keeps a few days.

Tinned potatoes are the key to a traditional one-pot camping meal, fried first if you have some oil or margarine with you. Then it depends what you feel like, but baked beans and peas can be used to make a corned beef hash.

Alternatively (using two pans of some sort)

- tinned tomatoes and dried herbs, with pasta on the side
- tinned/dried/fresh veg, whatever you can find or transport, and curry paste, with rice

You still only need one burner as one pan can be kept hot while serving as a lid for another, so long as you've got a level, stable base.

Comment: Canned potatoes is not something I have ever seen here (Sweden).

Comment: Here in the UK they're common. Even my local convenience store has them. While I do have a tin or two in the back of the cupboard I think of them as mainly camping food

Comment: Yes it seems good for that. I can get them from Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

Looks close to [Spam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_(food)), which is popular here in the US.

You can slice it and fry it in a pan, or over open fire to get it hot, then place it on a bun and make a sandwich/burger. Add some lettuce, pickle, ketchup, or whatever you prefer/can carry.

From the wikipedia article about [Bully Beef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bully_beef):

> Bully beef and hardtack biscuits were the main field rations of the British Army from the Boer War to World War II. It is commonly served sliced in a corned beef sandwich.

Dicing it and scrambling with eggs and diced potato (canned potato's work best since they're already soft) is also good. Also, just cooking slices and eating with fork and knife like a slab of meat is pretty good too.

Dicing it into cubes and tossing into a pot of Marconi & Cheese is also another common way to enjoy it.

Comment: I wasn't sure just frying it would be so good, but I'll have to try that also I guess.

Comment: @TomasBy I actually love Spam Burgers, and make them at home sometimes. Definitely a good camping/hiking meal if you can bring along the condiments and bun. From reading about the Bully Beef, it sure does look very similar/the same as Spam (which is just a brand name here in the US)

Comment: Tomas: I used to love fried slices of canned corned beef as a kid.  The secret is to completely cut the can all the way around both lids, then push it through so you get a cylinder of beef.  Then you can slice & fry the slices.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking out recipes on the websites of labels that produce tinned corn beef (one example below) as they will have put time and effort into testing the recipes they publish, which may have originated from contributions from the general public, but weeding out recipes that aren't consistently good. 
[https://www.princes.co.uk/recipes/?f=product&q=&t%5B%5D=Corned+Beef](https://www.princes.co.uk/recipes/?f=product&q=&t%5B%5D=Corned%20Beef) ...FYI I have no connection to Princes.co.uk - they just came up first in my online search.